# Bash scripting - dynamic curl post statement

Tags: bash, curl

i have a situation where i have to post data regularly to an api which in turns shows that data in website, i tested the post statement by using curl statement in ubuntu and it works fine, so i moved that script inside bash scripting so that i can create cronjob which runs every minute, here is part of the script where it reads the data from database and builds the statement and execute

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer astyiaklsdfijal=" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --data "$neww" \
   -X POST "$_url"
```

variable $neww was set from database.

when i run the bash script it gives me an error

```
{"errors":[{"id" : "0", "code" : "9000", "status" : "400", "title": "Bad Request", "detail": "JSONThreatProtection:
 Execution failed. reason: Expecting { or [ at line 1"}]}
```

but if i remove "$neww" variable and just put the whole text from $neww variable inside single quotes, it works fine but it wont work with the variable. Does anyone has any idea why this is causing that issue. i am new to curl and bash scripting

Comment: It sounds like the `neww` variable doesn't contain what you think it does. Without knowing more about how it's set, what it's supposed to contain, and what it actually does contain, it's hard to say what the problem is. The first thing I'd do is run your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net). if that doesn't fix it, put `set -x` before the section that deals with `neww` to get a trace of what's happening as it runs. If you need more info than that shows, add things like `echo "neww = '$neww'" >&2` to get print additional info as needed.

Comment: when i do echo "neww = '$neww'" >&2 i get neww = '{"effectiveDate": "2021-04-19T23:08:08.000Z", "externalId": "1591110169333", "isEncounterNote": false, "sho
wOnShiftReport":true, "noteType": "Skin/Wound Note","patientId": 74274, "sections": [{"name": "Note Text", "value":
 " wound "},{"name": "Provider", "value": "test"}]}' which is what i supposed to get and send it

Comment: What does `set -x` show? BTW, putting long segments of code/traces/etc in comments doesn't work very well; it's better to edit them into the question. If you need to put something like that in a comment, put it in backticks so it'll be formatted as code.

Comment: when i do set -x i get this error `curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 193:
'{"effectiveDate": "2021-04-19T23:12:59.000Z", "externalId": "1591110169639", "isEncounterNote": false, "showOnShiftReport":true, "noteType": "Skin/Wound Note","patientId": 74274, "sections": [{"name": "Note Text", "value": " wound "},{"name": "P
rovider", "value": "test"}]}'`

Comment: i put the command like this i hope i am doing correct `curl -H "$header" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d -x "$neww" \
   -X POST "$url"`

Comment: `set -x` has to be a completely separate command, not part of the `curl` command.

Comment: thank you very much Gordon, finally figured with set -x command that i am getting multiple single quotes which is throwing error, since from mysql i am already setting with single quote and bash script adding more single quotes, once i removed that everything working fine